# How to Use WebViewAssetLoader in Xamarin

Tags: javascript

I am making a 3D object viewer using xamarin, but I am trying to use WebView AssetLoader because AllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs has been disabled since Android 30 or higher, but I don't know how

```
        protected override WebViewClient GetWebViewClient()
        {
            return new PreviewWebViewClient(this);
        }

        private class PreviewWebViewClient : FormsWebViewClient
        {
            private readonly WebViewAssetLoader _assetLoader;

            public PreviewWebViewClient(WebViewRenderer renderer) : base(renderer)
            {
                _assetLoader = new WebViewAssetLoader.Builder()
                    .AddPathHandler("/assets/", new WebViewAssetLoader.AssetsPathHandler(renderer.Context))
                    .AddPathHandler("/file/", new WebViewAssetLoader.InternalStoragePathHandler(renderer.Context, renderer.Context.FilesDir))
                    .Build();
            }

            public override WebResourceResponse ShouldInterceptRequest(Android.Webkit.WebView view, IWebResourceRequest request)
            {
                return _assetLoader.ShouldInterceptRequest(request.Url);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

my code here WebViewAssetLoader is redline

I need a 3D web app that I can watch without the Internet